# No sound in Linux

Tags: fedora, audio, qubes

So sound used to work in my Linux distros. I use Qubes OS, Tails, and Fedora. All used to have sound but lost it for whatever reason even after fresh reinstalls. Pavucontrol in Qubes OS gives me "Dummy Output" as the only output device. Tails's sound manager gives me the same error. Initially it gave me an HDMI Unplugged error before I reset my BIOS configuration. I know you guys like terminal outputs so here's some. The commands below were run inside of Tails which is debian based:

```
amnesia@amnesia:~$ speaker-test 

speaker-test 1.1.3

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 192 to 2097152
Period size range from 64 to 699051
Using max buffer size 2097152
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 524288
was set buffer_size = 2097152
0 - Front Left
^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 speaker-test
```

Another command:

```
amnesia@amnesia:~$ ps -C pulseaudio
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  7801 ?        00:00:00 pulseaudio
  8678 ?        00:00:00 pulseaudio
```

And one more:

```
amnesia@amnesia:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And here's my hardware info:

```
amnesia@amnesia:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 78
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               625.634
CPU max MHz:           2800.0000
CPU min MHz:           400.0000
BogoMIPS:              4800.00
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp
```

`dmesg` output dump:
https://pastebin.com/NF8yE8u0

lspci output:

```
amnesia@amnesia:~$ (lspci -nn | grep -i audio)
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d70] (rev 21)
```

lsusb output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8086:0a66 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2a94:5241  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1058:0740 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Passport Essential (WDBACY)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 048d:1176 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Other info: This is a laptop. The internal speakers output no sound, and earphones aren't detected and don't output sound.

From what I am gathering from research, my OS isn't recognizing my soundcard, but it's weird it's happening for three distros. I'll be happy to follow advice from you all.

Comment: If your sound worked before you reset your BIOS settings, look there first. Post your motherboard model.

Comment: The resting of the BIOS only changed the error message, it didn't change the no sound issue.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for asking about hardware information. I neglected to have that in the first post. I added it now.

Comment: How are your speakers connected (analog to back of computer, digital via HDMI, ...)? What soundcard do you have (`lspci -nn | grep -i audio`)? Anything in `dmesg` that helps to explain why it doesn't find the soundcard/codec?

Comment: The first command returns nothing. My computer is a laptop. Going to paste the results of the former command.

Comment: I put an entire dump of dmesg in the question as a pastebin link because it's *huge*.

Comment: Not familiar with Qubes, but it looks like it suppresses the devices, which is why you got no soundcard. What does `lspci` and `lsusb` show? Have you  [setup a dedicated audio user](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/external-audio/) and [assigned the soundcard device](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/assigning-devices/)? Can you see more with `qvm-pci` and `qvm-usb` (these might need options, but I don't have the man pages)?

Comment: The QubesOS qubes were ignoring some hardware, so I switched to Tails (debian based distro) for the sake of this question. I updated the commands in this question accordingly. The terminal commands show the sound hardware, but the OS itself still doesn't play sound.